# Как размеры минимального и максимального стека влияют на скорость обработки данных?

Tags: delphi

У меня по большей части - обработка текстовой информации, чтение, запись.

По умолчанию, в настройках проекта стоят такие размеры:

```
Maximum Stack Size - 1048576
Minimum Stack Size - 16384
```

Если изменения влияют на скорость то какие параметры - должны быть (в большую или меньшую сторону). И что от чего зависит ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эти размеры практически никак не влияют на скорость работы.

Максимальный размер стека ограничивает место под локальные переменные.
Нужда в расширении этого места бывает редко, большие локальные статические массивы данных обычно не используют.

От размера стека также зависит глубина рекурсии, которая может случиться. Однако, если стек переполняется из-за рекурсии, нужно исправлять логическую ошибку, приводящую к большой (скорее всего - неограниченной) глубине рекурсивных вызовов.